# Please can you check my proof of de l'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

Statement: If $f,g : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable and $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+} g(x) = 0 $ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f'(x) \over g'(x)} = L$ then $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f(x) \over g(x)} = L$.

Proof: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. The goal is to find $\delta >0$ such that $0 < |x-a|< \delta$ implies $|{f(x) \over g(x)}-L| < \varepsilon$. Since $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f'(x) \over g'(x)} = L$  there is $\delta'>0$ such that $0 < |x-a|<\delta'$ implies $|{f'(x) \over g'(x)}-L| < \varepsilon$. By the mean value theorem there exists $c \in (a,a+\delta')$ such that 
$$ {f'(c) \over g'(c) } = {f(a + \delta') -f(a) \over g(a+\delta') -g(a) } = {f(a + \delta') \over g(a+\delta')}$$

That is, for every $\delta_n$ there exists $c_n \in (a,a+\delta_n)$ such that ${f'(c) \over g'(c)} ={f(a+\delta_n) \over g(a + \delta_n)}$. Hence if $\delta< \delta'$ then for every $x \in (a,a+\delta)$:
$$ \left | {f(x) \over g(x)} -L \right | =  \left | {f'(c) \over g'(c)} -L \right | < \varepsilon$$

Comment: How did you get the same $c$ to work for both $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @copper.hat He uses Cauchys version of the MVT, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks! I learn something new every day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the line of reasoning is fine in general

i) I'd suggest you mention that you use the not so well known Cauchy variant of the MVT,

ii) you don't get equality for the two  differences in the last formuala with display style for the given $x$ and

iii) the formulation 'that is, for every $\delta_n$... is confusing at first reading, at least for me. If you write: 'that is, if $0<\delta_n<\delta^\prime$...' I'd consider this to be easier to read. This point is nitpicking, however.

Comment: Thank you. The last line is a typo it should be $c$ not $x$.

Comment: Thomas, now I learned a bit more mathematics and now I think the first equality of displaystyle is also false because $f$ and $g$ are not defined at $a$.

Comment: @blue At a first glance this is formally correct, but by assumption you can continuously extend $f$ and $g$ to  $a$ by defining $f(a)= g(a)=0$.

Comment: I realised shortly after commenting. Thank you for your help. I now posted a revised proof using your help. What do you think of the revised proof? Is it better?

Comment: And even after revising: I believe there is the equality in the last equation of displaystyle. What am I missing?

Comment: @blue I can look into this only later.

Comment: Thank you! It is not urgent. Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: @blue Yes, that looks fine to me. In the first approach you've chosen $x$ after $c$ was found, actually you determined $c$ and then wrote down a claim for every $x$. But if you want equality in the displayed equation, you have to choose $c$ depending on $x$ (which you can, of course, do). Maybe that was what you meant, but for me as a reader this was not only not clear but appears to be the wrong way round. In your revised version you make that explicit, so there it is ok. There is, however, no need to have two names for that value, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would it be possible for you to also help me with [my newest question about this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772791/how-is-this-de-lhospitals-rule-simplified)?

Answer (score 1):

Proof: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. The goal is to find $\delta >0$ such that $0 < |x-a|< \delta$ implies $\left |{f(x) \over g(x)}-L \right | < \varepsilon$. Define $f(a) = g(a) = 0$. Then $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b)$. Since $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f'(x) \over g'(x)} = L$  there is $\delta'>0$ such that $0 < |x-a|< \delta'$ implies $\left | {f'(x) \over g'(x)}-L\right | < \varepsilon$. For every such $x$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x = a + \delta$ and by the mean value theorem there exists $c \in (a,a+\delta) = (a,x)$ such that 
$$ {f'(c) \over g'(c) } = {f(a + \delta) -f(a) \over g(a+\delta) -g(a) } = {f(a + \delta) \over g(a+\delta)} = {f(x) \over g(x)}$$

Then for every $x$ with  $0< |x-a|<\delta'$,

$$ \left | {f(x) \over g(x)} -L \right | =  \left | {f(a+\delta) \over g(a + \delta)} -L \right | =  \left |  {f'(c) \over g'(c) }  -L \right | < \varepsilon$$